# How do I create a followup LINQ .join() if an additional filter item is presented?

Tags: asp.net, linq

If I have a lystId, I want to include the MemberProductLyst object and filter by the LystId.

Any suggestions for the proper way to implement the follow up Lamba code inside of the
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lystId)) {} block below the initial query???

```
products = (from p in dc.Products
join t in dc.Tags on p.TagId equals t.TagId
join pi in dc.ProductImages on p.ProductId equals pi.ProductId
join i in dc.Images on pi.ImageId equals i.ImageId
where p.IsActive == true
where t.TagId == new Guid(brandId)
orderby p.CreatedOn descending
select new ProductItem
{
  productImage = i.FileName,
  productId = p.ProductId,
  description = p.Description,
  name = p.Name,
  adImage = t.AdImage
}).Skip(totalItemCount).Take(pageSize);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lystId))
{
  //Include MemberProductLyst table to Filter by lystId if LystId is available
  var memberLysts = from mpl in dc.MemberProductLysts
  where mpl.LystId == new Guid(lystId)
  select new { mpl.LystId, mpl.ProductId };

  products = (IQueryable<ProductItem>)products.Join(memberLysts, p => p.productId, mpl => mpl.ProductId, (p, mpl) => new {ProductItem = p, MemberProductLyst = mpl });
}
```

Comment: Is the purpose of the join to filter out certain products that don't have matches, or to ensure there are multiple instances of products that are associated with the same lyst multiple times? Or do you actually want to end up with information about the memberProductLysts that are associated with the given products?

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on the intent of your `Join`, but I suspect this may yield the results you're looking for:

```
products = products.Where(
    p => memberLysts.Any(mpl => mpl.ProductId == p.productId));
```